# in C# how to select specific Data from an XMLDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, xml-parsing

i got below response through web request

```
<Shofar Target_="Base" >
  <RapidOnSite_Pump Key="1" State="Idle" Amount="20" /> 
  <RapidOnSite_Pump Key="2" State="Idle" Amount="15" /> 
  <RapidOnSite_Pump Key="3" State="Despencing" Amount="25"/> 
- <Verb_List>
     <Verb_Item Key="1" Execute="RapidOnSite_Pump_AdHoc" Result="OK" 
      Detail="All Pumps►5" /> 
  </Verb_List>
```

from this string i only want to select Nodes which State is not Idle.

My Code

```
 string responseFromServer = MY_RESPONSE
     XmlDocument mainxml = new XmlDocument();
    mainxml.LoadXml(responseFromServer);

  XmlNodeList xnList = mainxml .SelectNodes("/Shofar/RapidOnSite_Pump [@State!='Idle']");
```

But by this code i didnt get requirments. can anyone please help me?

Comment: You have to use `XmlDocument` or you can use LINQ to XML?

Comment: anything. i just want required response.

Comment: Just checked your code - it works fine. One node is returned

Comment: are you sure ?, why i didnt get then. let me show my complete code

Comment: public void GetCartResponse()
        {
            string responseFromServer = "";
            responseFromServer = RetailLibrary.BusinessObject.Common.WebRequestCall("MyURL");
            if (responseFromServer != "")
            {
                XmlDocument mainxml = new XmlDocument();
                mainxml.LoadXml(responseFromServer);

                XmlNodeList xnList = mainxml.SelectNodes("/Shofar/RapidOnSite_Pump [@State!='Idle']");
            }
        }

Comment: Probably you don't have non-idle rooms in the response which you receive from server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145621/discussion-between-abhijit-pandya-and-sergey-berezovskiy).

Comment: i sent you message in private chat. can u pls check it?

Comment: Is `Shofar` the root element or is it nested in another node? Are there namespaces in the real xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the chat you show real xml. It contains the namespace which must be taken into account!

```
mainxml.LoadXml(responseFromServer);

XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(mainxml.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://ShofarNexus.com");

XmlNodeList xnList = mainxml.SelectNodes("/ns:Shofar/ns:RapidOnSite_Pump [@State!='Idle']", manager);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. now its working fine. its new knowledge for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XElement to get your work done, unless you want to stick to XmlDocument.

```
XElement rootElem = XElement.Load(new StringReader(xmlStr));
var rapidOnSitePumpWhichAreNotIdle = rootElem.Descendants("RapidOnSite_Pump").Where(e => e.Attribute("State").Value != "Idle");
```

At the end you will get `IEnumerable<XElement>` which can be iterated over.